# Executing commands based on the role inside a task in capistrano

Tags: ruby, jenkins, capistrano

I have a pseudo as follows

```
task :my_task, roles => [:role1, :role2] do
    command 1
    command 2
    command 3
    command 4
end
```

I want to run command 1 & command 2, only for role1, command 3 & command 4,for role2. Is this possible in capistrano?

I tried,

```
task :my_task, roles => [:role1, :role2] do
    on roles(:role1) do
        command 1
        command 2
    end

    on roles(:role2) do
        command 3
        command 4
    end
end
```

But didn't seem to work for me..Please help :)

Btwn, I'm using Capistrano v2.15.5

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Doesn't seem to work" means what? Is there an error?

Comment: Its not going to the 'on roles' code block at all :)

Comment: You said you are running Capistrano v2, but part of the syntax you've written is for v3. That's one reason why it won't work. Specifically, there is no such thing as `on roles(...)` syntax in v2.

Comment: Ah!Thanks for pointing that out :) Is there a away in v2 to get the similar functionality ? Currently I have divided into 2 separate tasks, each has role specific commands and they are getting triggered from  another helper function.Is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be a great way of solving it..but this was all I could and it worked for me.

```
task :my_task do
    task_1
    task_2
end
task :task_1, :roles => [:role1] do
    command 1
    command 2
end
task :task_2, :roles => [:role2] do
    command 3
    command 4
end
```